# Combine two arrays on php

Tags: php, arrays

Hello i am trying to combine two php array.

First one

```
array (size=13)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[30]
      public 'ID' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'html5' (length=5)
      public 'img' => string 'HTML5.png' (length=9)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[31]
      public 'ID' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'css3' (length=4)
      public 'img' => string 'css.png' (length=7)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[32]
      public 'ID' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'php' (length=3)
      public 'img' => string 'php1.png' (length=8)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[33]
      public 'ID' => string '4' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'java script' (length=11)
      public 'img' => string 'javascript.png' (length=14)
```

Second one

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[26]
      public 'ID' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'IDuser' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'IDskill' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[27]
      public 'ID' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'IDuser' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'IDskill' => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[28]
      public 'ID' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'IDuser' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'IDskill' => string '4' (length=1)
```

ID from first array is equal to IDskill from second array. I am trying to combine to create new array if IDskill and ID are same, with something like this in new array

```
          public 'ID' => string '1' (length=1)
          public 'name' => string 'html5' (length=5)
          public 'img' => string 'HTML5.png' (length=9)
   ===>New field  public 'MATCH' => string '1' (length=9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( where `a1` is first array and `a2` is second one and `$result` is final, merged array ):

```
$result = array();
$n=0;
foreach($a1 as $k=>$v) {
    if (isset($v->ID) && isset($a2[$n]->ID) && $v->ID==$a2[$n]->ID) {
        $result[$n]=$v;
        $result[$n]->MATCH=1;
    }
    $n++;
}
print_r($result);
```

Comment: close but i have here Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 12

Comment: I updated my answer with `isset` checking. The Notice You are getting is probably because the arrays have different size.

Answer (score 0):

use array_merge() function

```js
<?php
$a1=array("red","green");
$a2=array("blue","yellow");
print_r(array_merge($a1,$a2));
?>
```

or

```js
<?php
$fname=array("Peter","Ben","Joe");
$age=array("35","37","43");

$c=array_combine($fname,$age);
print_r($c);
?>
```

Comment: it's an example , how to combine or merge two arryas.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
<?php

$first_array = array(...);
$second_array = array(...);

// Anonymous function to extract the IDskills from the second array:
$get_IDs = function($element) {
    return($element->IDskill);
};

// Array of (just) IDskills of the second array:
$IDs = array_map($get_IDs, array_filter($second_array, function($element) {
    // Anonymous function to filter $second_array elements without IDskill:
    return(isset($element->IDskill));
}));

// Another anonymous function that returns a new array with elements from
// $first_array with the new MATCH property.
// use(&$IDs) makes $IDs available inside the function scope:
$check_match = function($element) use(&$IDs) {

    // We use clone because we don't want to modify the original array values:
    $match_element = clone $element;

    if(isset($match_element->ID))
        $match_element->MATCH = in_array($match_element->ID, $IDs);
    else
        $match_element->MATCH = false;

    return($match_element);
};

$match = array_map($check_match, $first_array);

?>
```

If you don't want to use the two first anonymous functions or don't want to create the `$IDs` array you can replace `use(&$IDs)` for `use(&$second_array)` and the line:

```
$match_element->MATCH = in_array($match_element->ID, $IDs);
```

for a loop that iterates through `$second_array` elements to check whether any of them has an `IDskill` equal to `$match_element->ID`.

Moreover, you may not need to check if `IDskill` and `ID` exist if all the elements in the arrays have the same properties.

Answer (score 0):

let me add my two cents, how to find element matching ID from the 1st array in the second one

```
   $tmp = array_filter($array2, function($ar2) use ($ID) { return $ar2->IDskill === $ID; });
   if ($tmp) // Found
   else // Not found
```

all code may be

```
result = array()
    foreach ($array1 as $item) {
        $ID = $item->ID;
        $tmp = array_filter($array2, function($ar2) use ($ID) { return $ar2->IDskill === $ID; });
        if ($tmp)  { // Found
            $tmp = $item;
            $tmp->MATCH = 1;
            result[]  = $tmp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @PatrikDupeliz Why you refused acception? Does something not work?